# How to solve an " Unresolved dependencies" error msg in compilation when creating a VS Code extension using Vue js and rollup.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vscode-extensions, rollupjs

I'm trying to render a Vue component inside a sidebar in a vscode application.
I'm getting an " Unresolved dependencies" error msg in compilation:

```
[0] (!) Unresolved dependencies
[0] https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
[0] vue (imported by web\pages\Sidebar.js, web\components\Sidebar.vue?vue&type=template&id=5b5bf828&lang.js)
```

I have followed the suggestion in the rollup docs to use @rollup/plugin-node-resolve but it doesn't work.

The compilation output:

```
> vscodereview@0.0.1 watch C:\Users\Dan Katorza\Desktop\vs2ndTest\vscodereview
> concurrently "rollup -c -w" "webpack --watch"

[1]     [webpack-cli] Compiler starting...
[1]     [webpack-cli] Compiler is using config: 'C:\Users\Dan Katorza\Desktop\vs2ndTest\vscodereview\webpack.config.js'
[0] rollup v2.60.1
[0] bundles web/pages/Sidebar.js → dist-web\sidebar.js...
[0] (!) Unresolved dependencies
[0] https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
[0] vue (imported by web\pages\Sidebar.js, web\components\Sidebar.vue?vue&type=template&id=5b5bf828&lang.js)
[0] created dist-web\sidebar.js in 124ms
[1]     [webpack-cli] Compiler finished
[1] asset extension.js 5.62 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main) 1 related asset
[1] ./src/extension.ts 832 bytes [built] [code generated]
[1] external "vscode" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
[1] ./src/SidebarProvider.ts 2.81 KiB [built] [code generated]
[1] ./src/getNonce.ts 411 bytes [built] [code generated]
[1] webpack 5.64.4 compiled successfully in 1253 ms
[1]     [webpack-cli] Compiler is watching files for updates...
```

this is the rollup.config.js content

```
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import esbuild from 'rollup-plugin-esbuild';
import filesize from 'rollup-plugin-filesize';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import postcssImport from 'postcss-import';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import requireContext from 'rollup-plugin-require-context';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

const postCssPlugins = [  
    postcssImport(),
];

export default fs  
    .readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "web", "pages"))  
    .map((input) => {   
        const name = input.split(".")[0].toLowerCase();  
        return {     
            input: `web/pages/${input}`,     
            output: {
                file: `dist-web/${name}.js`,
                format: 'iife',
                name: 'app',
                sourcemap: false,  
                globals: {
                    vue: 'vue'
                } 
            },
            plugins: [
                vue({ 
                    css: false,
                }),
                nodeResolve({  
                    jsnext: true,  
                    main: true, 
                    browser: true,  
                    dedupe: ["vue"],
                }),
                json(),
                
                alias({
                    entries: [{ find: '@',
                    replacement: __dirname + '/web/' }],
                }),
                image(),
                postcss({ extract: `${name}.css`,
                plugins: postCssPlugins 
            }),
            requireContext(),
            replace({   
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': production ? 
                '"production"' : '"development"',  
                preventAssignment: true,
            }),
            commonjs(),
            esbuild({ 
                minify: production, 
                target: 'es2015',
            }),
            production && terser(),
            production && filesize(),
            ],
            watch: {
                clearScreen: false,
                exclude: ['node_modules/**'],       
            },
        };
    });
```

This is the Sidbar.js content:

```
    import Vue from "vue";
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar.vue";

new Vue({render: h => h(Sidebar)}).$mount("#app");
```

This is the Sidbar.vue content:

```
    <template>  
    <div> 
        <p>Message received from extension</p>  
        <span>{{ message }}</span>

        <p>Send message to extension</p>
        <input type="text" v-model="text">
        <button @click="sendMessage">Send</button>

        <p>Open Vue App</p>
        <button @click="openApp">Open</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script> export default {
    data() {
        return {     
            message: '',
            text: '',   
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage);
    },
    beforeDestroy() {    
        window.removeEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage); 
    },  
    methods: {     
        openApp() {     
            vscode.postMessage({
                type: 'openApp',
            });
            this.text = '';  
        },
        sendMessage() { 
            vscode.postMessage({
                type: 'message',
                value: this.text,
            }); 
            this.text = '';  
        },
        receiveMessage(event) {
            if (!event) return;    
            
            const envelope = event.data;
            switch (envelope.command) {
                case 'message': { 
                    this.message = envelope.data;  
                    break;
                }
            };
        },
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    p {
        margin: 10px 0; 
        padding: 5px 0;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    span {  
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 5px;  
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: orange;
    }
    hr {
        display: inline-block;  
        width: 100%;  
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
</style>
```

This is the package.json content:

```
"scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "npm run package",
        "compile": "webpack",
        "watch": "concurrently \"rollup -c -w\" \"webpack --watch\"",
        "package": "webpack --mode production --devtool hidden-source-map",
        "compile-tests": "tsc -p . --outDir out",
        "watch-tests": "tsc -p . -w --outDir out",
        "pretest": "npm run compile-tests && npm run compile && npm run lint",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
        "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@rollup/plugin-alias": "^3.1.8",
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.1",
        "@rollup/plugin-image": "^2.1.1",
        "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.6",
        "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/glob": "^7.1.4",
        "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
        "@types/node": "14.x",
        "@types/vscode": "^1.62.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.1.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.1.0",
        "@vscode/test-electron": "^1.6.2",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.23",
        "concurrently": "^6.4.0",
        "esbuild": "^0.13.15",
        "eslint": "^8.1.0",
        "generate-source-map": "0.0.5",
        "glob": "^7.1.7",
        "mocha": "^9.1.3",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-esbuild": "^4.7.2",
        "rollup-plugin-filesize": "^9.1.1",
        "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-require-context": "^1.0.1",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-vue": "^6.0.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
        "typescript": "^4.4.4",
        "webpack": "^5.52.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "esbuild": "^0.13.15"
    }
}
```

Appreciate the help here as I can't seem to find the solution anywhere and sorry for the long post, I feel that it is important to show the code related.